# pd.to_datetime change date format producing wrong dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have extracted the table below from a csv file :

timestamp      user_id    cost   val1
01/01/2011            1         1     3
01/07/2012            1         19            57
01/09/2013            1         21            63
01/02/2011            2         20            8

And I for this purpose, I used the following statements :
import pandas as pd

```
newnames = ['date','user_id', 'cost', 'val1']
df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', names = newnames, header = False)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],format='%d%m%Y')
```

But the dates of table obtained in df are wrong : months and days are permutated without reason, i.e 01/09/2013 becomes 09/01/2013 without reason.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using and could you try: `df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', names = newnames, header = False, parse_dates=[0])` and see if this works

Comment: I am using anaconda that has automatically installed libraries such as pandas and IPython. How can I check my version in this last (However I believe my python version is 2.17).

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', names = newnames, header = False, parse_dates=[0]) does not work.

Comment: do `pd.version.version`

Comment: OK not sure, it could be what @filmor states, you could also try `df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', names = newnames, header = False, parse_dates=True)`, I notice that you don't include the separators in your format string:  `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],format='%d/%m/%Y')` don't you need '/' separators in your format string?

Comment: Also, my panda version is 0.13.1

Comment: 'df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', names = newnames, header = False, parse_dates=True)' seems working : ie 01/07/2012  remains 01/07/2012. However, if additinally I use df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],format='%d/%m/%Y'), 01/07/2012 becomes 2012-07-01 which is wrong. Even just df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']) produce wrong date while I really need this last statement.

Comment: You can pass `dayfirst=True` to `read_csv` or `to_datetime`, try both and see how they work for you

Comment: It seems working : I obtain the right dates format when I export the datas into a csv file.Thanks.

Comment: It is just a display issue so long as the dates were created correctly initially then it's just a display issue

Comment: "01/07/2012 becomes 2012-07-01 which is wrong" --> as far as I know this is *not* wrong (in most used format, although you can write a date in many ways ...). European 01/07/2012 (with day first) = 2012-07-01 in ISO format

Answer (score 9):

Hi it happens sometimes due to US/Europe time parsing compatibilties.

What I follow is,

> Case 1

If you are sure that your input file is having the time stamp in a correct format, and you want to use it on top of default parser, like in this case, use (as advised by @filmor) dayfirst option in `pd.to_datetime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)
```

> Case 2

When you are not sure about the correctness of the format, use the default,
    pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 7):

It is most certainly not random. Pandas defaults to the US date format and falls back if that doesn't make sense, i.e. `"12/3/2014"` becomes `2014-12-03` while `"13/3/2014"` will be parsed as `2014-03-13`.

You can pass `dayfirst=True` to `pd.read_csv` to force European-style date parsing.

Comment: How do you make dayfirst parameter to force European-style date parsing?